# a wide div with unlimited width

Tags: css

I've a big problem!

You know, a `div` default `width` is `100%` (of the parent). And if its content width is more than 100% (100%=1440px), `div` shows content in multiply lines.

Now, if i want, the div shows its content in one line, what should I do? look at the simple code::

```
<div>
    <div>aaa</div>
    <div>bbb</div>
    <div>ccc</div>
    <div>ddd</div>
    ......(more than 100 other div, with unknown width)
</div>
```

NOTE: I don't know the content width.

I tried `display: inline;` and `display: inline-block;` and `display: table;`. they didn't work.

NOTE 2: I tried `display: -moz-box;`. It works, but Only in FIREFOX!
Thanks ...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The simplest way is to use [`white-space: nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/white-space) on the parent, and `display: inline-block` on the children:

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/4Yv83/

I also added `overflow-x: auto`, because presumably you [don't want this](http://jsfiddle.net/4Yv83/1/).

Answer (score 5):

Just tell the text inside the div not to wrap.

```
div {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a few years passed but ... I think it would be better to set overflow to hidden, because we don't need to show all of children elements at once. we use this kind of styling in thumb-slide like components. so I suggest to set "overflow:hidden" to parent element.

```
/* for parent element */
overflow: hidden;
```