# Fit container-div width to floated div children and allow side-scrolling with only css?

Tags: javascript, css, css-float

I'm trying to make a side-scrolling layout with content that's loaded dynamically in the container div. The children divs in the body div are floated left and can be any width.

```
<div id="container" style="overflow-y:hidden, overflow-x:scroll">
    <div style="float: left">Lots of images and text</div>
    <div style="float: left">More images and text</div>
    <div style="float: left">Even more</div>
</div>
```

I basically need to make this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zepva/) work so the inner divs are side-by-side, scrolling left-to-right, and there can be any number of them.  The container div is also resizable ;]

Is it possible to do this with only css? Do I have to use javascript?

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690302/a-wide-div-with-unlimited-width/6690373#6690373

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/zepva/1/

```
#simulating_body {
    width: 98%;
    border: 3px solid #222;
}

#middle {
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.inner{
    display: inline-block;

}
```

Some tips: You can not use an ID more than once, so where you had `#inner` on the two inner divs, that wouldn't work.

You had the right idea using inline-block, but you had it on the wrong elements.

Use `inline-block` on the elements you want to be side by side, and then use `white-space: nowrap;` on their parent element to make sure they on the same line.

Comment: Both floats and inline-blocks fail when they have padding. 
 
The scrollable content (all the children as a single page scrolling inside the parent) fails to calculate the width, so a big chunk remains outside the visible area, whose width equals the sum of all the padding of the children elements.
Fiddle at http://stackoverflow.com/q/23976017/595488

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can do it with floats, but `display: inline-block` should work:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div>Lots of images and text</div>
    <div>More images and text</div>
    <div>Even more</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 100px;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
div {
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here's a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/uguhiz/1/edit