# Expand the parent div of floated elements to fit their total width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to put together a page that will have a horizontally scrolling pane on it - here is an example of the layout I am looking to get: [image]
The content is dynamically added and has varying dimensions. .

Here's some HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Base CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.container .inner {
    position: relative 
}

.container .inner > div {
    float: left;
}
```

Currently the only way I can get it working is by setting an explicit width for `.inner`. Otherwise, closest I've come is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17310577/fit-container-div-width-to-floated-div-children-and-allow-side-scrolling-with-on) answer, but it's still pretty far off my desired effect. Is it possible to achieve what I'm looking for with HTML/CSS alone or will I have to resort to javascript?

Comment: FYI with `display: inline-block` you just need to set the text to `vertical-align: top` and that will bring it back up. Is there a reason you can't set an explicit width for `.inner`?

Comment: Either way, when with `inline-block` the `.inner` container width isn't the total of its children.

Comment: yeah i know, that was just a side note. So what's the reason you cant set a width on `.inner`?

Comment: The size/amount of the floated elements changes, so I need a dynamic width.

Comment: gotcha, yeah your best bet is probably with javascript. You can determine the size of the boxes on load and adjust the container width to match

Comment: That's a last resort, hopefully someone has a trick up their sleeve but otherwise that's what I'll be doing...

Comment: Do you have to support old IE?

Comment: If you do not need to support old IE, you can achieve what you want with `display: inline-block` Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eZ4j4/ - you can test the width of the inner div and see that it should have the width of all items combined. This is based off one of the answers, with the small addition of the inner container.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you expected? **http://jsfiddle.net/GE5Hf/4/**

[image]

Just use `white-space: nowrap` together with the `inline-block` and `vertical-align: top`. You don't need your `.inner` div to achieve the desired effect - just use one container with `overflow-x: auto`:

```
<div class="container">
        <div id="i1"></div>
        <div id="i2"></div>
        <div id="i3"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap; 
}

.container > div {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Note: it is better to use `overflow-x: auto` than `scroll` just in case the scrollbar is not needed.

**EDIT:** We were speculating whether you actually need that .inner div. If you need it, you can just add it back with no special style required: http://jsfiddle.net/GE5Hf/5/

**EDIT 2:** To have the `.inner` div the width as its children, simply give it `display:inline-block`: **http://jsfiddle.net/GE5Hf/8/**

**EDIT 3:** Tried what you suggested in your last deleted comment, i.e. remove the fixed width of the child. This was really tricky, I had to wrap each child element to special div with `display: table-cell` and the `inner` div gets `dislay: table-row`: **http://jsfiddle.net/GE5Hf/12/**

Comment: It appears as though you are missing one HTML element. See my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/eZ4j4/ - I believe he wants one containing element called "inner" which will have the width of all items combined.

Comment: @codefactor - I think you are yet another victim of [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/166308) :-) We have to try to distinguish in the OPs question what is the *purpose* and what is only a *means* to achieve that purpose. I think no user will miss some "inner div" if the page looks and behaves as expected :-)

Comment: My intuition says that you are correct, but I can think of several reasons one would want an inner div to have the width of all items combined. Perhaps it is because he knew no other way to achieve the result. Perhaps it was because he wanted a padding and/or border around the entire block of items, but inside the scroll instead of around it. Or perhaps he wanted to use the offsetWidth value for some strange layout reasons?

Comment: @codefactor that's all possible, but then the purpose should be mentioned in the question and let us optimize that. Anyway, it's not very complicated to add it back again.

Comment: One other thing I should point out, if you look closely at the OPs mockup, there is a green area around the elements and a black background behind the "inner" but still within the "container" - but I agree that the purpose to the "inner" was not explicitly defined in the text portion of the question.

Comment: @codefactor I don't see anything green in the question image... anyway look at my jsfiddle, the background effect is there.

Comment: To me it seems dark green but it is gray (#393939) My eyes are tricking me.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for all your responses. The problem is that with this solution `.inner` has a width that is only equal to `container`. If you notice the question I linked in the OP has the same solution. `.inner` needs to be as wide as the content that it contains, as it will be scrolled using software that checks an elements width to identify scrolling bounds (default scroll is currently very laggy on some devices).

Comment: @styke, aha! You didn't mention this. What about this? http://jsfiddle.net/GE5Hf/8/ (updated my answer)

Comment: @Tomas my sincere apologies, I accidentally edited that part out of the original post :s I currently favour your latest solution, please give me a bit of time to try and implement it

Comment: @styke no problem. Advantage of this simplistic solution is that it doesn't need the position attribute which could possibly collide with other elements in more complex layouts etc. The more complex CSS & HTML you have the more likely the chance - that's why I like to simplify.

Comment: @styke, I started to investigate your problem but you deleted your last comment. Is it still present?

Comment: @styke, tried what you suggested in your deleted comment, see the update.

Comment: @Tomas thanks, I really appreciate your effort. You've solved my problem and beyond!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using CSS only.

Here's a <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mathijsflietstra/rY2Au/)</kbd>.

The solution is to set `position: relative;` on `.container`, which creates a new stacking context inside the `.container`, setting `position: absolute;` and `white-space: nowrap;` on `.inner` ensures that `.inner`'s content `div`'s will not wrap to the next line and that `.inner` will grow with its content, adding  `display: inline-block;` and `vertical-align: top;` on the `.inner > div`'s ensures that they are treated as inline elements and stick to the top of their containing element.

I believe this is what you are after, I have checked on the latest versions of IE, Chrome, Firefox and Safari and it works fine on all of them, I have no reason to believe that it won't work on older versions.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 220px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
.container .inner {
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #FFCCFF;
}
.container .inner > div {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Wow! I was just a *few* seconds faster, with basically the same idea :-) I am always the slowest :) Please note that this solution can be much much simplified, see my answer.

Comment: Yes I noticed, the reason for the extra `div` in my example is simply because when I read the question it seemed that OP has a specific need to expand the inner `div`, and you've just left it out all together, which off course is a simpler solution to the general layout question. We'll see how it goes from here :)

Comment: We have to be careful not to fall into [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/166308) :-) I think the "inner div" is not the ultimate goal, only attempted *means* to achieve that goal. I think no user will miss some "inner div" if the page looks and behaves as expected :-)

Comment: @Tomas, Yes you're right that it could be XY, but just like @codefactor, I can think of reasons for specifically wanting that `.inner div`.

Comment: My pleasure, don't forget to mark this answer with the green tick :)

Answer (score 0):

Is position: relative mandatory ?

```
.container .inner {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TKRMB/)

Comment: This is not what OP wants. Just give the .inner divs more widths and you'll see it will stop working: http://jsfiddle.net/TKRMB/5/

Answer (score 0):

@styke You can do that with `display:inline-block`(and some font-size on .inner > div) and `font-size:0` to div.inner.
Provided fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zepva/4/ , ignore the colors, i used them only for demonstration
`font-size:0` will remove the gaps between the element using `display:inline-block` so when you will get the total width of the `div.inner`, that will be the sum of children divs

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this, no script was necessary:

```
.container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;

    background-color: silver;
}

.container .inner {
    white-space:nowrap;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow-x: scroll;

    background-color: gray;
}

.container .inner > div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;

    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/er144/4FLWK/

Answer (score -1):

`display:inline-block`, with `vertical-align:top` , that way your text wont fall at the bottom of the container.

```
.container .inner > div {
    display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: See my response to jmore's comment